# Can you identify this uniform?

Tags: military, identification

[image]

Photo was found in a trunk belonging to my great grandmother, grandparents, passed on to uncle.

Comment: Welcome Peg to the History Stack Exchange. Can you give us a little more information? Particularly any possible family background? Where did your grandparents live? Did they immigrate? Did their family members immigrate? Are there any inscriptions on the back? To me it looks like an artillery uniform from late 1800's to early 1900's but the above questions would help a lot.

Comment: Also, the clearer and higher resolution of a pic you can provide, the better. Fine details in identification questions make all the difference.

Comment: The stack of cannnballs makes this look like an artillery uniform, but an infantry or cavalry person could also pose in front of a stack of cannonballs.   I note that in the USA army, the insignia of branches included crossed weapons, cannons for the articller, sabers for the cavalry, and rifles for the infantry.  They were often displayed with the regimental number above the crossing point and the company letter below the crossing point.  There seem to be such insignia on the collar and maybe on the cap.  You need to post clearer pictures of them.

Comment: In the US army, which he is not guaranteed to belong to, the diagonal stripe on the left arm near the cuff should indicate he completed one enlistment and reenlisted. I tis also possible that he was a student at some school wearing a school uniform.

Comment: @MAGolding: Whoa! Those aren't normal cannonballs. Even a 32 lb shot is barely a 6" diameter, and these look to be at least 8" diameter, possibly 9". The former would be 64 lb, and the latter 100 lb, each. At any time after invention of photography the weapons launching those is likely a fairly short list.

Comment: Presumably they are mortar bombs, which were roughly spherical in the 19th century, and used by the coast artillery and as siege weapons.  ( https://civilwartalk.com/threads/the-dictator-a-13-inch-seacoast-mortar.168351/ is about one example )

Comment: Looks like US Army, garrison uniform, not full dress since there is no apparent color bad around the cap, circa 1902 . . . branch insignia is not clear, a higher resolution photo would be nice, but, despite the cannonballs, I suspect he is in the infantry.

Comment: See See https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/62717/what-time-period-is-this-uniform